# bootstrap dropdown not working when created an instance of Modal object in bootstrap in angular project

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap dropdown suddenly not working after creating instance of any Modal, Popover etc that we had in node modules. What I was trying to do is to make use of the show method inside the Modal class to open the bootstrap modal.

I am using bootstrap 4.6 with angular 12

**DropDown code**
`

3

```
<div class="dropdown-menu notification-menu-container p-0 m-0">
    <div class="dropdown-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-between align-items-stretch">
        <div class="notification">
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                  This is some text within a card body.
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="notification">
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                  This is some text within a card body.
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="notification">
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                  This is some text within a card body.
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="notification">
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                  This is some text within a card body.
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="notification">
            <div class="card m-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                  This is some text within a card body.
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="notification-footer mt-3 w-100 bg-white align-self-center text-center">
            <a class="nav-link h6 text-info " routerLink="/notification"><u>View all Notifications</u></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

**Code for the Modal**

```
<div class="notification-container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>
      
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" #notificationModal>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Code that created an instance of bootstrap

```
`import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notification-home',
  templateUrl: './notification-home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notification-home.component.scss']
})
export class NotificationHomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('notificationModal') content: any;
  //modalInstance: Bootstrap.Modal;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public open = ():void => {
    debugger
    this.content.open();
    //let xx = new Bootstrap.Popover(null, null)
    let xx = new Modal(document.getElementById("exampleModal"), {});
    // new Modal(document.getElementById("exampleModal"), 
    //  {
    //   backdrop: "static",
    //   keyboard: true
    //  });
    // this.modalInstance.show();
  }

}`
```

**angular.json**

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

Is the approach is the right approach to open a modal from a component ? Once I removed

```
let xx = new Modal(document.getElementById("exampleModal"), {});
```

everything will works a normal, including the dropdowns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Importing straight from 'bootstrap' causes the dropdown listeners to disappear.

Fixed it by using deeper import:
import Modal from 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';

Same could be used for Popovers I guess: import Popover from 'bootstrap/js/dist/popover';

Goes to category: I dont know why but it works.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was getting headaches because my dropdowns stopped working and I couldn't understand why. Your answer fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me as well. What a pain!

Comment: I also had some similar issues where the nav-bar and the drop-down also was broken when I get any bootstrap instance (like toaster, modal,...) by importing in angular ts files. Here is my answered question with an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68647181/bootstrap-5-with-angular-12-bootstrap-navbar-dropdown-interactions-are-bloc/68664655#68664655

Comment: You are a legend!