# Bootstrap 5 with Angular 12 : bootstrap (navbar, dropdown) interactions are blocked after get/create bootstrap instances by JavaScript

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

Everything (navbar, dropdown) works fine until I try to get/create bootstrap instances in the .ts files. When I insert the get/create instance js code I can't collapse the nav-menu after I expanded and the dropdown is not working either!

Here is the source code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ah3inn)

If you are commenting out the following code part, everything works fine!

```
 var modal = new Modal('#updatePwaModal');
 modal.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049609/bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-when-created-an-instance-of-modal-object-in-boots?rq=1) that is answered in another question where the dropdown is broken when a modal instance is created. In my case, the dropdown and also the navbar was broken!

Instead of the

```
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';
```

needed

```
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';
```

Answer (score 1):

If somebody still suffers from this - above solution did not helped for me - but this one did:

```
import Modal from 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal'
```

The only change is deleting curly braces from the statement. I'm using vue 3 composition api - maybe that is where the difference comes from.